# ¿Qué herramienta utilizar para crear pruebas de rendimiento a un servidor que recibe muchas descargas?

Tags: rendimiento, jmeter

Estaba utilizando JMETER para hacer pruebas de rendimiento y las que realice fueron:
- Peticiones http , con 2000 threads - 3 veces en periodo de tiempo de 5 segundos a archivos .pdf

pero se satura la aplicación al hacer demasiadas peticiones al servidor y al final no hace ninguna, 
Quisiera saber sí hay alguna otra herramienta que sirva para este tipo de caso el cual implica hacer pruebas al servidor con descargas masivas a archivos .pdf con un peso 4 mb a 50 mb para ver sí el servidor soporta y atiende a todas las peticiones.

Comment: ¿2000 threads en que periodo de tiempo? ¿Cuántos estas lanzando por segundo?

Comment: @YemisiSCG , gracias ya edite el contenido.

Comment: Para aclararlo un poco. En tu plan en JMeter tienes: Number of Threads = 666. En Ramp-Up Period = 5 y en Loop Count= 3  ???

Comment: Number of Threads = 2000. En Ramp-Up Period = 5 y en Loop Count= 3

Comment: Wooow! eso quiere decir que estas mandando 1200 peticiones por segundo. ¿Cuál es el promedio de las peticiones que reciben por día? Pregunto ya que según tus pruebas estarían recibiendo 4,320,000 peticiones por hora. En realidad no creo que eso suceda!

Comment: En realidad no haría esas peticiones por una hora, solo quiero saber como reacciona el servidor ante picos altos ya que tengo 20000 usuarios de los cuales por lo menos se conectaran al mismo tiempo 5000 usuarios y podría llegar a 10000.

Por eso mi pregunta ¿Qué herramienta utilizar para crear pruebas de rendimiento a un servidor que recibe muchas descargas?
ya que JMETER se satura y hace que la aplicación se cierre y al final no lanza las peticiones.